# Spring Boot Docker layers with transitive dependencies

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, spring-boot-maven-plugin, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I've multiple Microservices with varied 3rd party dependencies, currently using default spring boot docker layers which copies all the dependencies to same dependencies layer. However I want to split the dependencies into core and dependencies layer. core layer contains `spring-boot-starter-webflux`, `spring-boot-starter-actuator`, `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` and rest of the dependencies like jpa, streams etc goes into dependencies layer.

```
bootJar {
    enabled = true
    archiveFileName = "${archiveBaseName.get()}.${archiveExtension.get()}"
    layered {
        application {
            intoLayer("spring-boot-loader") {
                include "org/springframework/boot/loader/**"
            }
            intoLayer("application")
        }
        dependencies {
            intoLayer("application") {
                includeProjectDependencies()
            }
            intoLayer("snapshot-dependencies") {
                include "*:*:*SNAPSHOT"
            }
            intoLayer("core") {
                include "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:*"
                include "org.springframework:spring-webflux:*"
                include "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:*"
            }
            intoLayer("dependencies")
        }
        layerOrder = ["core", "dependencies", "spring-boot-loader", "snapshot-dependencies", "application"]
    }
}
```

The problem here is layering include doesn't include dependencies transitively. For example `spring-webflux` doesn't include `reactor`, `netty` transitively. I need to mention the dependencies manually. Is there a way to include the dependencies transitively only for `core` layer and not for `application` or `snapshot` and rest of the dependencies to `dependencies`.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I am also looking to transport all core springboot libraries in one layer and others separately as one of my project uses jpa and other uses mongodb.